# laravel eloquent relation between 4 table

Tags: laravel

I have four tables `post` `user_post` `user_info` and `users`.

Here I am giving four query that I want to do with eloquent.

for `post` table: (Model: `post`)

`$post_id = select id from post`

for `user_post`(Model: `Userpost`)

`$student_id = select student_id from user_post where post_id = $post_id`

for `user_info` table:(Model: `userInfo`)

`$user_id = select user_id from user_info where student_id = $student_id`

for `user` table:(Model: `user_table`)

`$student_name =  select name from user where $student_id = $user_id`

and finally print this $student_name.
What I want to do is,
One single post can have many student. I want to print those student name.

Comment: Try this: `select name from user where student_id in (select user_id from user_info where student_id in (select student_id from user_post where post_id in (select id from post)))` .

Comment: There could be multiple student for a single post. And one more thing actually I want to build eloquent relationship between those table to find student name

Answer (score 1):

Add these realtions to Post model to get users and user_post

```
//post has one user post
public function userPost(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Userpost','post_id','id');
}


//post has many users
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\user_table','user_id','student_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a relation on the `Post` model to users:

```
public function users() {
      return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'student_id');
}
```

Then query for users like:

```
$posts = Post::with('users')->get();
$names = $posts->users->pluck('name');
```

Comment: it says `Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Answer (score 0):

Try Nested Eager Loading

```
//Post Model
public function user_post (){
     $this->belongTo('user_post');
}

//user_post model
public function user_info(){
     $this->belongTo('user_info');
}

//user_post model
public function user(){
     $this->belongTo('user');
}



On your controller
Post::with('user_post.user_info.user')->where('id',$post_id)->get();
```

Hope that help